# Is it necessary to use Vuex for a Vue-based shopping cart?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to let two separate Vue components communicate with each other (not siblings, so not child or parent).

Let's assume I have a Laravel blade template file like that:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="header">
     <shopping-cart></shopping-cart>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     <products-list></products-list>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I send a product from component to component (putting products to the cart) ?

Comment: One solution is to use event bus to share data between components: https://andrejsabrickis.medium.com/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860

Comment: Also, you can use localStorage to store the data nd then access it.

Comment: You are free to implement global state yourself without Vuex but then you're on your own with maintaining it and keeping it in sync with back end or local storage.

Comment: no - you can use composition api to solve the same problem - https://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-shopping-list-app-with-the-vue-composition-api/

Comment: The cart seems to be a component that should be available from any page. Using Vuex for this seems like a solid strategy that is suited for these scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the right solution with the right structure, and it's simple, you have to use the State Manager(Vuex), because it's the best solution.
I wanted to write this in the comment, but I could not because I did not have enough reputation.

Comment: By the State Manager do you mean Vuex?

Comment: y, the state manager of vue is vuex bro, @tiborm100